# Opening Word document while C# .NET application is still running

Tags: c#, .net

I've written following code after referring to various questions on StackOverflow and some blogs to create a word document for inserting images through C#. In my standalone PC I'm able to run this and open the document created finally even when the application is still running(which is what I require) but when I run the same application in a windows server machine, the word document generated as output, I'm unable to open it. The error thrown is Used by some other process and says that I have to save the changes made to the template (some .dot file I guess).

I observed a few changes in the development environments. I'm running in a Visual Studio 2010 targeted for 3.5 framework while the server 2003 PC contain Visual Studio 2008.

The namespace Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word; is in the COM tab in my PC, while it is present in the .NET tab of target machine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace Snapper
{
    class WordDocumentGenerator
    {
        public void CreateWordDocument(string fileName)
        {
            string originalPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string path = originalPath;
            path += @"\snapshots";


            Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
            wordApp.Documents.Add();
            wordApp.Visible = false;
            Word.Document doc = wordApp.ActiveDocument;            
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


            string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(image);
                //Goto End of document
                wordApp.Selection.EndKey(Unit: Word.WdUnits.wdStory);
            }

            //doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path + @"\snap2.jpg");

            path = originalPath;
            path += @"\documents";

            DirectoryInfo docDir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            if (!docDir.Exists)
            {
                docDir.Create();
            }   

            string savePath = path + @"\" + fileName + ".doc";

            doc.SaveAs(savePath,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing
               );
            doc.Save();
            wordApp.Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone guide in making the required changes to the code so that my application enables me to open the created word documents while it is still running.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code worked fine on my machine.  This indicates a configuration problem on the target machine.

Comment: Yes, this is the same problem that I've mentioned in the question. I'm still looking for a solution